# Not found exception smallrye-kafka producer in quarkus application

Tags: kafka-producer-api, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

have a simple poc built on quarkus to send a avro message to a kafka topic.

below is the configurations that were loaded -

acks = 1
batch.size = 16384
bootstrap.servers = [kaas-test-dc-a.company.com:443]
buffer.memory = 33554432
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
client.id = kafka-producer-cpe-reply
compression.type = none
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
enable.idempotence = false
interceptor.classes = []
internal.auto.downgrade.txn.commit = false
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
linger.ms = 0
max.block.ms = 60000
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
max.request.size = 1048576
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 10000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retries = 2147483647
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
security.protocol = SSL
security.providers = null
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 127000
socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.engine.factory.class = null
ssl.key.password = [hidden]
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
ssl.keystore.key = null
ssl.keystore.location = C:/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.certificates = null
ssl.truststore.location = C:/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
transactional.id = null
value.serializer = class io.apicurio.registry.utils.serde.AvroKafkaSerializer

Below is the error am seeing - 
2021-06-29 23:36:59,012 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.uti.AppInfoParser] (Quarkus Main Thread) Kafka version: 2.7.0
2021-06-29 23:36:59,012 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.uti.AppInfoParser] (Quarkus Main Thread) Kafka commitId: 448719dc99a19793
2021-06-29 23:36:59,015 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.uti.AppInfoParser] (Quarkus Main Thread) Kafka startTimeMs: 1625024218998
2021-06-29 23:36:59,757 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) aru-unet-Service-replyws 1.0.0 on JVM (powered by Quarkus 1.13.7.Final) started in 33.944s. Listening on: http://localhost:8080
2021-06-29 23:36:59,758 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2021-06-29 23:36:59,761 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [camel-support-retrofit, cdi, kotlin, mutiny, quarkiverse-apicurio-registry-client, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-openapi, smallrye-reactive-messaging, smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka, swagger-ui, vertx]
2021-06-29 23:37:00,049 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.cli.Metadata] (kafka-producer-network-thread | kafka-producer-cpe-reply) [Producer clientId=kafka-producer-cpe-reply] Cluster ID: 6cbv7QOaSW6j1vXrOCE4jA
2021-06-29 23:40:09,465 INFO  [ServiceResponseServices] (executor-thread-1) Sending response string to Kafka
2021-06-29 23:40:10,206 ERROR [io.sma.rea.mes.kafka] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-14) SRMSG18206: Unable to write to Kafka from channel cpe-reply (topic: kaas.aru-unet.dev.prcngevts.v1): javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: Not Found
at io.apicurio.registry.client.request.RequestHandler$ResultCallback.onResponse(RequestHandler.java:38)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:129)
at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:174)
at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Would appreciate some help on the exception above.

Comment: Is the Avro schema registered in the schema registry? If not, and you want the client to register the schema automatically, you can add `mp.messaging.outgoing.[channel].apicurio.registry.global-id=io.apicurio.registry.utils.serde.strategy.GetOrCreateIdStrategy` to your `application.properties`.

Comment: HI Ladicek. I have the property already listed. below are the list of all properties I have used in application.properties

Comment: kafka.bootstrap.servers=kaas-test-ctc-a.company.com:443
mp.messaging.connector.smallrye-kafka.apicurio.registry.url=http://test-schema-registry-a.company.com
mp.messaging.connector.smallrye-kafka.security.protocol=SSL
mp.messaging.connector.smallrye-kafka.ssl.keystore.location=C:/keystore.jks
mp.messaging.connector.smallrye-kafka.ssl.keystore.password=####
mp.messaging.connector.smallrye-kafka.ssl.key.password=#####
mp.messaging.connector.smallrye-kafka.ssl.truststore.location=C:/truststore.jks
mp.messaging.connector.smallrye-kafka.ssl.truststore.password=#####

Comment: mp.messaging.outgoing.channel.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.outgoing.channel.topic=kaas.aru-unet.dev.prcngevts.v1
mp.messaging.outgoing.channel.message.key.expression=kafka-integration
mp.messaging.outgoing.channel.value.serializer=io.apicurio.registry.utils.serde.AvroKafkaSerializer
mp.messaging.outgoing.channel.apicurio.registry.artifact-id=io.apicurio.registry.utils.serde.strategy.SimpleTopicIdStrategy
mp.messaging.outgoing.channel.apicurio.registry.global-id=io.apicurio.registry.utils.serde.strategy.GetOrCreateIdStrategy

Comment: mp.messaging.outgoing.channel.apicurio.registry.avro-datum-provider=io.apicurio.registry.utils.serde.avro.ReflectAvroDatumProvider

Comment: That sounds weird. Can you verify the Avro schema actually ends up being registered in the registry?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of that exception is that you need a permission to write messages to the topic or basic authentication may need to access the schema registry?!